# error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before when creating a struct array

Tags: c, struct

I'm learning C language and I have a problem.

I have a struct and I initialize it with {0}:

```
struct first
{
    char a[5];
    int b;
}first= {0};
```

And I'm trying to create a array of this struct in another struct with each element in the array has the value of {0}:

```
struct second
{
    first f_array[20];
};
```

However, when I compile, it says error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'first'.

Anyone knows how to create a struct array in other struct like what I'm trying to do?

Comment: first={0}, this is something new! Does it work?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted `struct first f_array[20];`?

Comment: Sure it does. @kiner_shah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the compiler can't resolve the type of `first` unless you include the keyword `struct` in the declaration of the array like this :

```
struct first f_array[20];
```

Or use `typedef` :

```
typedef struct {
    char a[5];
    int b;
} first;

struct second {
    first f_array[20];
};

struct second obj = {{0}};
```

Using `typedef` means you no longer have to write `struct` all over the place and makes your code more cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what I'm trying to do is when creating the struct array, let each element in the array to be the value {0}. I'm wondering to declare the array like this, would the value {0} be assigned to the each one of the elements?

Comment: At first I tried to use typedef, and if I have "} first;" in the last line, it of course works fine. But it doesn't assignment the value {0} I want to initialize to the struct. And I tried "} first = {0};" but it said error: typedef 'first' is initialized.

Comment: Just declare an object of type `second`, like this : `struct second obj = {{0}}`. It will initialize each struct to 0. @GeorgeSha

Comment: Thank you! I think I begin to understand how these things work.

Comment: No problem. Read `Kernighan & Ritchie`, it's a very good book for `C` beginners. @GeorgeSha and pardon me, if I am asking too much, but try considering seeing my other answers, and upvote them. :)